# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, navigation, constants, react-props

I am trying to navigate from one screen to other screen inside tabbar in react native.
But, I am getting following error

```
  ButtonClickCheckFunction = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('detailsScreen', { detailsScreen: jsonData });
  }
```

Any suggestions?

For main screens, In tab bar we have created stack,

```
    const AppStack = createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator({
      Dashboard: {
        screen: ProfileStack,
      },
      Connect: {
        screen: Connect,
      },
      screen1: {
        screen: Screen1,
      }

});
```

But, In Dashboard screen we are showing tabbar. I am working with tab2. So, From tab2, I have details screen. In that details screen I have to show navigation bar with back button arrow like custom image.

So, How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Provide full code

Comment: This is full code. But, we have used stack navigator for other screens, We are using tabbar. Inside one tab, I have to navigate to other screen which is from same tab.

Comment: updated my query, please check

Comment: Which component has `ButtonClickCheckFunction` inside of it?

Comment: It's like some button on press action

Comment: Is the function in `ProfileStack`, `Connect`, or `Screen1`?

Comment: Those are all components which are from side view controller

Comment: where is 'detailsScreen' defined ?

Comment: That is not main screen only side view bar components are defined in stack. Tabbar defined dashboard class.

Answer (score 1):

If you post more code, we'll be able to better answer your question.

From the error message though, it seems like you're not properly creating the component so that the `navigation` property is set. You'll need to make sure to wrap the component using the [`withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/with-navigation/) higher order component.

```
export default withNavigation(MyComponent);
```

Comment: OMG, Thanks a lot brother. Here is my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799976/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-objectevaluating-navigation-state-react-nativ,,just answer this,., I will approve, You just saved my life.